# Powershell equivalent of Cat ./* ../path2/* > file.sql

Tags: powershell, cat

I'm trying to translate a Linux command to be easily usable for Windows user for a project, but I am not having any luck finding comparable commands in Powershell.

I have two paths with some SQL and CSV files. What I need is this command:

```
cat ./* ../path/* > new_file.sql
```

This takes all content from all files in path1 and then all content from all files in path2 and writes it to a file.

I assumed I could do something similar in Powershell, but apparently the behaviour is wildly different.

What I have tried are:

```
cat ./*, ../path/* > new_file.sql
```

```
Get-Content ./*, ../path2/* | Out-File new_file.sql
```

They both do the same which seems to... I'm not sure, take the entirety of path2/* for every file in path1? The output quickly balloons to tens of megabytes. The combined content of both directories is a perhaps 40 kilobytes.

Anyone know? I cannot find a proper answer to this. Thanks!

**EDIT: I think I figured out what the problem is. I guess I should've just used the actual paths for the example. First path is `./*` and it seems like it keeps looping over the Out-File it makes itself. I have updated the title and examples to reflect this.**

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, I get expected behavior (contents of all files in path1, and contents of all files in path2). Can you supply a sample directory listing + samples of output? (try running against two dummy folders with a smaller amount of files)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen my mistake. I figured out what caused the problem and have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate the files as a separate step before concatenating their contents (this way `Get-Content` won't accidentally discover the new file halfway through):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem ./,../path2/ -File
$files |Get-Content |Out-File newfile.txt
```

You can combine these statements in a single pipeline if you wish:

```
(Get-ChildItem ./,../path2/ -File) |Get-Content |Out-File newfile.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, works exactly like I want. Thank you very much for the quick answer!